# Возможно ли получить HANDLE с помощью QSerialPort аналогичный HANDLE получаемому с помощью CreateFile (winapi, <windows.h>)?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qt5, serial

Возможно ли получить HANDLE с помощью QSerialPort аналогичный HANDLE получаемому с помощью CreateFile (winapi, )?

Есть код написанный на С++ и WinApi, в нем для обращения к устройству порт открывается с помощью:

```
LPTSTR port_name = TEXT("COM5");

HANDLE hCom = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)port_name,
                    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    0,
                    NULL);
```

Код выше меняю на:

```
HANDLE hCom;
QSerialPort *serial;
serial = new QSerialPort();
serial->setPortName("COM5");
serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud38400);
serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

hCom = serial->handle();
```

После этого изменения в коде обмен данными с устройством перестает работать.
Код компилируется без ошибок, GetLastError при открытие порта возвращает 0.
При записи в порт с помощью WirteFile, GetLastError начинает возвращать ошибку 997 ERROR_IO_PENDING.

Comment: Зачем вам этот хандлер? Если вы используете Qt, в классе QSerialPort всё необходимое имеется. ОС напрямую тут вообще не нужно теребить.

Comment: >>при открытие порта возвращает 0<< То есть, после этого кода, вы умудряетесь попытаться открыть порт через полученный хандлер?

Comment: @test123 Хандлер нужен чтобы в процессе переработки кода старый код продолжал работать. Когда GetLastError - возвращает 0, это как раз таки хороший признак, означающий что ошибок не возникло.

Comment: Поясните что вы делаете. Вы открываете порт в Qt, далее пытаетесь использовать WinApi? Вас тут ничего не смущает?

Comment: @test123 Да, пытаюсь открыть порт с помощью Qt и связать со старым WinApi кодом с помощью QSerialPort::handle().  Глобальная суть задачи - добавить новые возможности протокола, и переработать библиотеку с С++ & WinApi на C++ & Qt. Из-за большого объема работы по хорошему какое-то время надо чтобы WinApi и Qt сосуществовали вместе.

Comment: Qt - это POSIX, он не привязан к ОС, WinApi - это чёрный ящик виндоуза. Я бы никогда не поверил что они могут сосуществовать. Для того чтобы ваш переход был безболезненным, вы должны были озаботиться этим на стадии проектирования и сделать промежуточный класс/контейнер, и обращаться к своему интерфейсу, который бы прокидывал сообщения, например в WinApi.

Comment: @test123, Qt и нативные функции ОС прекрасно сосуществуют вместе, т.к. кьют собственно их и использует. В виду универсальности кьют некоторые специфичные функции ОС могут отсутствовать в интерфейсах и именно для этого предоставляется доступ к нативным дескрипторам объектов, чтобы можно было получить дескриптор (окна, файла, сокета и т.д.) и работать с ним на уровне апи ОС.

Comment: @goldstar_labs, соглашусь, я не прав, для временного костыля сойдёт)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего не выйдет, т.к. QSP не только открывает порт в overlapped режиме, но и запускает WaitCommEvents (как минимум), и стартует мониторинг событий на хендле. И как только в порт что-то придет, то QSP автоматически сам вызовет ReadFile. И по аналогии, если вызвать на полученном хендле WriteFile, то QSP автоматом промониторит ее завершение и сделает обработку, т.к. он мониторит открытый хендл на операции ввода-вывода.

QSP::handle() нужен чтобы дать возможность делать некоторые ioctrl's, если ооочень нужно (например, что-нибудь подправить в DCB структуре).

PS: А то что Вы делаете, это порнография (да еще и какая), оно не заработает, или будет постоянно крешиться.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение. Конечно порнография, но с чем только в рабочих задачах не приходится сталкиваться. Пойду перелопачивать все WriteFile/ReadFile в старом коде

Answer (score 0):

@Geek16bits ERROR_IO_PENDING не является ошибкой.
Данный код обозначает, что операция чтения/записи выполняется асинхронно. Это обусловлено тем, что винапишный код у вас открывает порт в синхронном режиме, а кьют - в асинхронном (флаг FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED).

К сожалению, в коде кьют флаг FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED проставлен константно и избежать его не удастся.
Код:

```
bool QSerialPortPrivate::open(QIODevice::OpenMode mode)
{
    ...

    handle = ::CreateFile(reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(systemLocation.utf16()),
                              desiredAccess, 0, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, nullptr);

    ...
```

Одним из вариантов решения для вас является доп.проверка возвращаемого значения функций ReadFile/WriteFIle на код ошибки ERROR_IO_PENDING
Например так:

```
    if (ReadFile(m_hPort, buff_current, bytes_to_read, &read_current, &m_ovRead) == FALSE)
    {
        DWORD error_code = 0;

        error_code = GetLastError();

        if (error_code != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            // Show error

            return 0;
        }
        // Skip empty read attempts
        continue;
    }
   // Append read data to read buffer
```

Подробнее про FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED: http://pblog.ru/?p=74
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: спасибо за ответ, закрыл некоторые пробелы в понимание процесса.